# How to join two query that compare different results?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `match` that contains all the `matches` of a soccer competition. The structure of the table is the following:

```
id | round_id | datetime | status | home | away | result
```

essentially each `match` have a `status` that indicate:

1. Scheduled
2. Postponed
3. Canceled
4. Playing
5. Finished

there is also the `round_id` that indicate the reference of the `competition`.

In my application I check each time if a specific `round` need to be updated. For doing so, first I check if all the `matches` of the league contains a status of `3` or `5`. The query is the following:

```
SELECT (COUNT(*) = SUM(status in (3, 5)) 
                   AND COUNT(*) = 380) AS result 
                   FROM `match` WHERE round_id = 10
```

So if the `380` matches are cancelled or are finished, then the `round` 10 is updated.

If the result of the query above is false, so the round need to be updated, then I have to check which `matches` need to be updated.

For doing that I wrote the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS result FROM `match` m2 
                   WHERE m2.round_id = 10
                   AND m2.datetime < NOW() AND m2.status IN (1, 2)
```

the query above check if there are `matches` with a `datetime` lower than the current one, and if the status of them is `1` or `2`, specifically (scheduled and postponed).

I'm not really satisfied about my implementation for the following reasons:

1. I need to execute two query for check if I need to update.
2. The last query return the number of the `match`, but my goal is return a `boolean`. Unfortunately my skills of `sql` is not so advanced.

Is possible join this two query in one to simply the checking?

Thanks in advance for the help.

**UPDATE - DATABASE WITH DATA STRUCTURE**:

```
id | round_id |        datetime      | status | home | away | result
 1      10      2018-08-15 00:00:00      5        A      B     1-0
 2      10      2018-08-15 00:00:00      5        C      D     1-1
 3      10      2018-08-15 00:00:00      5        E      F     2-1
 4      10      2018-08-15 00:00:00      5        G      H     2-2
```

the `matches` above are all updated 'cause the status is `5` so the `round` 10 doesn't need any update. The first query will return  `true` and the second query will return 0.

Consider now this example:

```
id | round_id |        datetime      | status | home | away | result
 1      11      2018-08-15 00:00:00      5        A      B     1-0
 2      11      2019-08-15 00:00:00      1        C      D      
 3      11      2019-01-15 00:00:00      5        E      F     2-1
 4      11      2019-03-12 00:00:00      1        G      H
```

the `round` 11 need to be updated because we have 2 `matches` that are scheduled, but only the `match` with the `id` 4 has already played, so the query need to return `false` because the `round` 11 isn't updated.

Comment: @LukStorms Sorry for this, I updated the question with a practice example and dataset, hope this will clarify the question better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT (COUNT(*) = SUM(status in (3, 5)) AND
        COUNT(*) = 380 AND
        SUM(mdatetime < NOW() AND status IN (1, 2)) = 0
       ) AS result 
FROM `match`
WHERE round_id = 10;
```

I think you just want to check if the second query returns a count greater than 0.  In any case, you can combine all these conditions into a single boolean result.

Comment: `m2` is match? I can't see it declared

Comment: @sfarzoso . . . It is not needed.

Comment: I tested the query again and not works, the bug is on that part: AND SUM(datetime < NOW() AND status IN(1, 2)) > 0 essentially, if all the matches have as status 5 and the datetime is less than the current then the query will return false but it must return true because the round is update . Should I replace with: `AND SUM(datetime < NOW() AND status IN(1, 2)) = 0`?

Comment: @sfarzoso . . . If you want the inverted logic, then use `= 0`.  It wasn't clear to me what logic you wanted.